# HTML parsing with BeautifulSoup in Python unknown error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, cjk

I know that this code works for other websites that end in .com

However I noticed that the code doesn't work if I try to parse websites that end in .kr

Can somebody help to find why this is happening and an alternate solution to parse these types of websites?

Following is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://everytime.kr/@nN4K1XC0weHnnM9VB5Qe'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='container')
print(results)
```

The URL here is a link to my timetable. I need to parse this website so that I can easily collect the information for the subjects and data relevant to the subject (duration, location, professor's name, etc.).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website is serving dynamic content and you get an empty response back - you may use selenium.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://everytime.kr/@nN4K1XC0weHnnM9VB5Qe'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='container')
print(results)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Can you explain to me about the driver part (5th line)?  Why do you choose the executable path as chromedriver.exe?

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/

Comment: Thanks! Downloaded the chromedriver.exe and placed it under the C drive and got it working.

Comment: Sorry to ask you another question, but why would you use time.sleep?

Comment: No problem - Used time cause wont confuse with all the additional selenium stuff like [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) but take a look it will give you the change to wait until elements are loaded...